# Page not scrolling HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I am just playing around with HTML and CSS but I can't get this page to scroll down, no matter what. The only thing that worked for me is to scale the HTML page to x<1.0. I want to place the divs in a block and one div should occupy 100vh.
HTML and CSS code is attached below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  transition: 1.3s all ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

.lev1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  background: url('res/bg1.png');
  background-size: cover;
}

.lev2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: red;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Danish Shakeel</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<!--Progress Bar-->
<div class="header">
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    // When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
    window.onscroll = function() {
      myFunction()
    };

    function myFunction() {
      var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
      var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
      document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
    }
  </script>

  <body>
    <div class="lev1">
      Level1
    </div>
    <div class="lev2">
      Level2
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Mashiro Tried that as well. Still won't work

Comment: Why have you set your body to `position: absolute`? That will just create trouble in the future because it will loose all it's height.

Comment: @RickardElimää I was seeing if seeing a position explicitly would work, didn't work the other way around as well.

Comment: Seems to be working just fin in the snippet. Other issues: Your transition should be `transition: all 1.3s ease-in-out;` as the correct syntax is `transition: <property> <duration> <timing-function> <delay>;`. `body` is already a block element.

Comment: @AlexG Should I try moving the divs out of body?

Comment: @DanishShakeel No, you should be applying the styles to a `div` with a class instead. Also  `html` should not be `display: flex;`, that might actually be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is scrolling fine for me which probably indicate it doesn't work for a particular browser. You have malformed HTML which need fixing anyway to eliminate that this is not the problem.

You have HTML outside the <body> when it should be inside it. Also, this bit of html

```
<!--Progress Bar-->
<div class="header">
    <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

is missing a

```
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might just be a case of badly written HTML and CSS, due to lack of experience. I've cleaned up your code and fixed all major issues, please tell us if the result provides a satisfactoy answer.

The following issues were fixed:

- `html` should not be `display: flex;`
- `body` is already a block element
- the transition should be `transition: all 1.3s ease-in-out;` as the correct syntax is `transition: <property> <duration> <timing-function> <delay>;`
- `body` should not be a child of `div`, do basically all of your HTML **inside** the `body` tag
- some style cleanup for the `html` and `body` tags
- By John's answer a closing `</div>` is missing

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  transition: all 1.3s ease-in-out;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.lev1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  background: url('res/bg1.png');
  background-size: cover;
}

.lev2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: red;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Danish Shakeel</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <script>
    // When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
    window.onscroll = function() {
      myFunction()
    };

    function myFunction() {
      var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
      var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
      document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
    }
  </script>
</head>



<body>
  <!--Progress Bar-->
  <div class="header">
    <div class="progress-container">
      <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lev1">
    Level1
  </div>
  <div class="lev2">
    Level2
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```